# Answered....Bootstrap 4 Card and Firefox issue with opening links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Below is a sample of my Bootstrap card code.  I need to make the card open the hyperlink if the user links on the card itself OR they click on the card title. The following code works everywhere but in Firefox. In Firefox, if you click on the card, it works. If you click on the card title, Firefox opens TWO new windows.

Any ideas please? Thanks.

```
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 column checklist">
     <div class='card h-100' onclick="window.open('https://help.cccis.com/training/repair_facility/estimating/checklists/ChangeChecklistDisplayOrder.pdf','_blank');">

     <div class="card-body">
     <h4 class="card-title">
     <a href="https://help.cccis.com/training/repair_facility/estimating/checklists/ChangeChecklistDisplayOrder.pdf" target="_blank">Change Checklist Display Order</a>
      </h4>

      <p class="card-text">This job aid describes how to change the Direct Checklist display order.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">2 pages <img src="images/pdf3.png" align="right" width="17" height="20" alt="Job Aid"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: When you're clicking on **.card** you're clicking on **<a>** as well because it is a child element. You need to use stopPropagation to fix it. Maybe: `<a onclick="event.stopPropagation();" href="...">Change</a>`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your saying the stop would tell the card to ignore the href. BUT its the other way around.  The onclick works just fine.  Firefox fires BOTH events if you click on the href, opening two windows?

Comment: Well, my english is intermediary, but I will try to answer...
Although you're using onclick event in **.card**, **<a>** is a child element so when you click on **.card**, you're clicking on it too. Using stopPropagation() will fix your problem.

Comment: You can learn more about stopPropagation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation
There are other ways to fix it, of course.
You could create a custom event using addEventListener and custom attributes for example.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  Your English is just fine to my eyes.  I think I understand.  Basically it is telling the onclick to be ignored by the href.  I will give it a try

Comment: IT WORKED. Thank you so much!  How do I mark this answered?

Comment: I think it is not necessary, I'm glad I helped you, but if you want a "custom event" to fix this problem I can create it. Regards ^^